# Sessions are not persistent [PASSPORT]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am trying to implement login through OAuth 2.0, however I can't make my sessions persist, it seems right after a users has been authenticated their session is gone. Also, the app seems to get stuck in routes/bnetauth.js at the redirect in the callback function.

These are the files where I use passport

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
//TOOLS
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session'); //Persistant sessions
var passport = require('passport');
//REQUIRE MODELS
require('./models/News');
require('./models/Application');
//REQUIRE ROUTES
var bnetauth = require('./routes/bnetauth')(passport);
var api = require('./routes/api');
var public = require('./routes/public');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/karatechop');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('views'));
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch', // session secret
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Use Routes
app.use('/auth', bnetauth)
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/admin', admin);
app.use('/', public);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/bnetauth.js (Logging in through battle.net, hence the bnetauth name)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


module.exports = function(passport) {

    router.get('/bnet',
        passport.authenticate('bnet'));

    router.get('/bnet/callback',
        passport.authenticate('bnet', {
            failureRedirect: '/' }),
        function(req, res, next){
            console.log('Authenticated: ' + req.isAuthenticated())
           ####THIS IS WHERE IT GETS STUCK####
            res.redirect('https://localhost:3000/');
        });
```

config/passport.js

```
var BnetStrategy = require('passport-bnet').Strategy;


var BNET_ID = 'hidden'
var BNET_SECRET = 'hidden'

var User = require('../models/user')


// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {
    console.log('Entering passport')
    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('Serializing')
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            console.log('Deserializing')
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use(new BnetStrategy({
        clientID: BNET_ID,
        clientSecret: BNET_SECRET,
        region: 'eu',
        callbackURL: "https://localhost:3000/auth/bnet/callback"
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile)
        console.log(accessToken)
        User.findOne({id: profile.id}, function(err, user){
            console.log("Trying!")
            if(err)
                return done(err);

            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                var newUser = new User();

                newUser.id = profile.id,
                newUser.token = accessToken,
                newUser.battle_tag = profile.battletag

                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;

                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    }));
};

    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem!

The problem was in my serialize and deserialize functions in `config/passport.js`

On my user model, I had two forms of ids.

1. The _id applied by mongo
2. The id that I save from the users object passed back to me from battle.net       (this is the ID of the user on battle.net).

In serialize, the id that would be used when serializing the user to the session would be the battle.net id (since I was calling `user.id` and not `user._id`

Then, in the deserialize when extracting data from the user object, I was using mongo's findById function, which uses the `._id` (which is totally different from `.id` in my user's object, hence it returned `'undefined'`.

Changing the `.id` to `._id` in the serialize function solved my problem, and sessions are now working and are persistent.